Why I can notinstall husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule On laravel 10 / livewire 3 site?
On laravel 10 / livewire 3 site I try to add husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule package, but I have an error :
$ composer require "husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule:*" -W
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:56
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Problem.php:366
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule[dev-main, v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.2] require awcodes/filament-table-repeater ^1.2 -> found awcodes/filament-table-repeater[v1.2.0, ..., 1.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.0.4).
    - husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule[dev-dependabot/github_actions/dependabot/fetch-metadata-2.2.0, dev-tenancy, v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.3] require awcodes/filament-table-repeater ^2.0.4 -> found awcodes/filament-table-repeater[v2.0.4, ..., 2.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.0.4).
    - Root composer.json requires husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule * -> satisfiable by husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule[dev-dependabot/github_actions/dependabot/fetch-metadata-2.2.0, dev-main, dev-tenancy, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.3, 9999999-dev].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their
In my composer.json:
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "akaunting/laravel-money": "^5.2.0",
        "awcodes/filament-table-repeater": "^3.0.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.2.0",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^6.11.0",
        "bezhansalleh/filament-exceptions": "^2.1.1",
        "botman/botman": "^2.8.3",
        "botman/driver-web": "^1.5.3",
        "codewithdennis/filament-select-tree": "^3.1.41",
        "filament/filament": "^3.2-stable",
        "filament/spatie-laravel-media-library-plugin": "^3.2.92",
        "filament/widgets": "^3.2-stable",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.8.1",
        "hasnayeen/themes": "^3.0.23",
        "igaster/laravel_cities": "^1.3.12",
        "jeffgreco13/filament-breezy": "v2.2.1.1",
        "joaopaulolndev/filament-edit-profile": "^1.0.20",
        "joshembling/image-optimizer": "^1.4.1",
        "lara-zeus/popover": "^1.1.5",
        "laravel-notification-channels/telegram": "^4.0.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.48.14",
        "laravel/pennant": "^1.8.2",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3.3",
        "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^2.5",
        "laravel/telescope": "^4.17.6",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9.0",
        "leandrocfe/filament-apex-charts": "^3.1.3",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.5.1",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1.55",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.4.2",
        "omar-haris/filament-timezone-field": "^1.0.3",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^3.0.4",
        "petercoles/multilingual-country-list": "^1.2.12",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "^1.2",
        "predis/predis": "^2.2.2",
        "pxlrbt/filament-environment-indicator": "^2.0.1",
        "saade/filament-adjacency-list": "^3.2.1",
        "saade/filament-fullcalendar": "^3.2.2",
        "spatie/emoji": "^4.1.1",
        "spatie/geocoder": "^3.16",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^4.8",
        "spatie/laravel-login-link": "^1.2",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^10.15.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.11.1",
        "spatie/laravel-translatable": "^6.7.1",
        "staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list": "^1.20.1",
        "stichoza/google-translate-php": "^5.1.3",
        "symfony/process": "^6.4.8",
        "vimeo/laravel": "^5.9",
        "wisdom-diala/countrypkg-laravel": "^1.0.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^v2.15.1",
        "beyondcode/laravel-er-diagram-generator": "^2.0",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.29.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.16.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.30.2",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6.12",
        "nonsapiens/realaddressfactory": "^2.0.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.4.0",
        "nunomaduro/larastan": "^2.9.7",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.6.19",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.8"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "files": [
            "app/Library/helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
            "@php artisan filament:upgrade"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}

Not sure is this package compatible with laravel 10 / livewire ?
If yes, which steps have I to take to install the package ?
MORE COMMAND :
$ composer require husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:56
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884
Using version ^2.0 for husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Problem.php:366
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule[v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.3] require awcodes/filament-table-repeater ^2.0.4 -> found awcodes/filament-table-repeater[v2.0.4, ..., 2.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.0.4).
    - Root composer.json requires husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule ^2.0 -> satisfiable by husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule[v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.3].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Thanks in advance!

Have you previously installed awcodes/filament-table-repeater? this package version is conflicting with the version of husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule.And that is why you are getting this error.

Yes, I have installed before "awcodes/filament-table-repeater": "^3.0.4" - which is latest version of this package. Not sure which version have I to edit for awcodes/filament-table-repeater manually? I prefer to use latest packages?

If husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule package does not work with latest filament are there similar packages with similar functionality ?

The updated version of husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule is 2.0.3 as per https://packagist.org/ and this require a min version of 2.0.4 for this awcodes/filament-table-repeater.I am not sure but I would suggest you to run composer require husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule(which will install updated version) to check if it resolve the issue.Currently you are not installing the updated one as per the error log. Do and check it.

I tried and have  errors in MORE COMMAND  block

Then you need to downgrade the version of awcodes/filament-table-repeater in order to install the updated version of husam-tariq/filament-database-schedule as per the information that error logs says.

Not shure, I want it. Are there some other plugins with functionality like filament-database-schedule package ?

This is one of the alternative. Check this out in the link https://github.com/spatie/laravel-schedule-monitor

I suppose it must have livewire wrapper plugin? Are there any ?
